# My code contains and error of Forgotten to declare when I run it?

Tags: java

I don't understand how to fix this error or even what this means. My results need to look like this:

```
Guess the maximum Integer value: 
543214

You were off by 2146940433

Guess the minimum Integer value: 
2145678321

You were off by 1805327
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class ExtremeMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create a Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Create an Extremes object
        Extremes extreme = new Extremes();

        // Ask the user to guess the maximum value of an Integer
        System.out.println("Guess the maximum Integer value: ");
        input.nextInt();

        // Compute and display the difference
        // between the max and the guess
        System.out.print("You were off by " + maxDiff());

        // Ask the user to guess the minimum value of an Integer
        System.out.println("Guess the minimum Integer value: ");
        input.nextInt();

        // Compute and display the difference 
        // between the min and the guess
        System.out.println("You were off by " + minDiff());


    }
}


    public class Extremes
{
    Integer min;
    Integer max;

    // Constructor
    public Extremes()
    {
        //Set min and max values
        min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    // Returns the difference
    // max - number
    public Integer maxDiff(Integer number)
    {
        return max - number;
    }

    // Returns the difference
    // min - number
    public Integer minDiff(Integer number)
    {
        return min - number;
    }

    // Returns a String representation
    // in the form
    // [min, max]
    public String toString()
    {
        return "[" + min + ", " + max + "]";   
    }
}
```

Comment: At the very least it's : extreme.maxDiff() and extreme.minDiff(). Thos are methods from your Extreme class, so they have to be called on your extreme object.

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker  When I put extreme.maxDiff() and extreme.minDiff() it gives an error "Method is expecting type Integer and type no arguments was given".

Comment: Use `int`, not Integer, for numeric values.  `int` is a primitive (just four bytes) while Integer is a full object.  Doing math with Integer objects can involve a lot of object creation and garbage collection, which can impair performance.  Even Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE are `int` values, not Integer objects, despite being declared in the Integer class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have commented your errors, but did not tested it.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Create a Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Create an Extremes object
    Extremes extreme = new Extremes();

    // Ask the user to guess the maximum value of an Integer
    System.out.println("Guess the maximum Integer value: ");
    int max = input.nextInt(); // your first error, assign input to integer, 

    // Compute and display the difference
    // between the max and the guess
    System.out.print("You were off by " + extreme.maxDiff(max)); // your second error, invoke emthod by ref 

    // Ask the user to guess the minimum value of an Integer
    System.out.println("Guess the minimum Integer value: ");
    int min = input.nextInt(); // yout third error assign input to int

    // Compute and display the difference
    // between the min and the guess
    System.out.println("You were off by " + extreme.minDiff(min)); // and again invoke method correctly


}
```

you have to assign input to int and then invoke method from your class to find dif